# What is the current record for highest temperature for superheated liquid water at 1atm?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

We know that water at 1atm can be superheated [well beyond 100C](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48271/is-there-a-limit-on-how-hot-you-can-superheat-water-at-1-atm). Can someone link to a paper with the current demonstrated record?

Comment: The recently published ["Approximations for the nucleation temperature of water"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931023001254) may have useful information and pointers to references.

Answer (score 0):

The thermodynamic limit of superheat for water is 302 C. Thermal inkjet printheads routinely heat water-based inks to about 260-280 C.

Comment: Why 302C specifically and not something closer to 370C near the critical point?

Comment: @KFGauss, because the superheat limit is defined at one atmosphere pressure. The critical point is at elevated pressure.

Comment: A reference would be useful.

Comment: try Avedisian 1985 to start with.